# No member function to call to try_emplace in std::unorderd_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

My map is

```
std::unordered_map<int,int> m_A2PMap;
```

and this is how i am putting values in it.

```cpp
m_A2PMap.try_emplace(getID(),getWaitSecond());
//getID and getWaitSeconds will return int and they both are non-const
```

But it's not allowing me to do it and showing this error

```
candidtate function template not viable:'this' argument has type 'const std::unordered_map<int,int>': but method is not marked const.
```

Any Help would really be appreciated.

Comment: The above code works for me on MSVC. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Well i am using gcc

Comment: Please post a [mre] - the error suggests that your `m_A2PMap` is `const` in the context of that call

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Looks like this code is run from a method which is marked as `const`. This implies that all fields are `const` that is why you code produces this error. To proper fix this we need much more context - more code with explanation what it suppose to do. Crappy fast advises are: "drop `const` from method" or "add `mutable` to this field". Most probably problem is in some other place.